# C# HttpListener not responding

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, web-services, http

I have some issues creating a local webserver using the HttpListener. When I use localhost uri (or 127.0.0.1), it works just fine and nicely responds to the requests.

However, when I add some madeup domain, like "whateverabc.com", the server is not responding to requests anymore and chrome is printing ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error.

What I am missing? Thanks!

```
 public class WebServer
{
    private readonly HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
    private readonly Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> _responderMethod;

    public WebServer(string[] prefixes, Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method)
    {            
        if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
            throw new NotSupportedException(
                "Needs Windows XP SP2, Server 2003 or later.");

        if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");

        if (method == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("method");

        foreach (string s in prefixes)
            _listener.Prefixes.Add(s);

        _listener.IgnoreWriteExceptions = true;
        _responderMethod = method;
        _listener.Start();
    }

    public WebServer(Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method, params string[] prefixes)
        : this(prefixes, method) { }

    public void Run()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Webserver running...");
            try
            {
                while (_listener.IsListening)
                {
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((c) =>
                    {
                        var ctx = c as HttpListenerContext;
                        try
                        {
                            string rstr = _responderMethod(ctx.Request);
                            byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstr);
                            ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
                            ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                        }
                        catch { } // suppress any exceptions
                        finally
                        {
                            ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                        }
                    }, _listener.GetContext());
                }
            }
            catch { } // suppress any exceptions
        });
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _listener.Stop();
        _listener.Close();
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebServer ws = new WebServer(SendResponse, "http://whateverabc.com:54785/");
        ws.Run();
        Console.WriteLine("A simple webserver. Press a key to quit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
        ws.Stop(); 
    }

    public static string SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
    {
        return string.Format("<HTML><BODY>My web page.<br>{0}</BODY></HTML>", DateTime.Now);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a fundamental misconception of what's going on. Here's the thing:

By registering a prefix you simply tell your webserver to serve requests that start with that prefix and go to the given port.

However, when you use Chrome (or anything else really) to access your website there will first be a DNS request to your configured DNS server to find out which IP address the "whateverabc.com" domain points to. And since this address simply doesn't exist (you can check on https://www.whois.com/) your request fails. So your webserver does not receive a request to start with.

Think about it this way (or try it out): If you were to start a webserver on your local machine and make it listen to requests that start with "http://www.microsoft.com", would you really expect your call from Chrome to access your local web server when you type in the microsoft website?